# Timing of execution of setter method

Tags: ruby, setter

The following code:

```
class A
  def foo= foo; puts "b" end
end
A.new.foo=("foo").tap{puts "a"}
```

results in `"a"` being printed before `"b"`, which means that `tap` is called before the setter method `foo=`. This is counter-intuitive to me, as I thought that method chaining works from left to right. In this example, it looks like the setter method is skipped and is executed later. Nevertheless, it is clear that setter methods are not always executed last in a code. Then, at what timing is this `foo=`, or setter methods in general executed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue you have is that you are not really calling `foo=` method, but you execute assignment. Ruby interprets it as:

```
A.new.foo = ("foo").tap{puts "a"}
```

Hence it firstly executes tap on 'foo' and then executes assignment.

To see that everything is fine try:

```
A.new.send(:foo=, 'foo').tap {puts 'a'}
```

Comment: This shows that `x.foo = y` is not syntax sugar for `x.foo=(y)` with method `foo=` taking an argument `y`, but is something else.

Comment: Yep, this can also be seen by noting tht return value of the setters is being ignored completely.